# Proving that relative gain array is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Any help appreciated for the solution direction. [image: View question here]

Comment: This follows from the facts that the transposes, inverses and Hadamard products of positive definite matrices are positive definite. (That Hadamard products of positive definite matrices are positive definite is known as [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem)).

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, I did not think in that direction. Yeah its easy that way.